# 'Add a Page' Missing

Tags: sharepoint-designer, wiki-pages

In a Sharepoint site, the menu that drops down from the gear is supposed to have an option, "Add a Page". I don't have this button. When I go to the wiki page where there should be a button "+ Add a New Page", there is nothing. In Sharepoint Designer, I can't edit the Home Page to add links to pages I create in SPD. I have every level of permission as well. This seems to be a common enough problem and there are plenty of answers around but I have gone through every one I can find and none of them have helped.

Answer (score 0):

I found a work around which just makes me more confused about the original problem. I can write in a link on the Home page to a page that doesn't exist and then Sharepoint gives me the option to create it because it can't be found (e.g. [[Page]] would prompt a "'Page' doesn't exist, would you like to create it?" dialogue box). If there is no problem with creating pages though, why can I not find this button in the first place?